# Reference request on Combinatorics and set theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am thinking about teaching an introductory class in Combinatorics and Set Theory. My view on this is that much of the introductory part in combinatorics can be seen as finite set theory.

The issue is that I am having a hard time finding an appropriate (recommended) textbook, can anyone suggest one?

Thank you.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan No, this would be an inclass teaching only.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Well I might end up typing my lecture notes in LAtex, at which point I will make them available, but that would probably take few years :)

Comment: I really like [Grimaldi](https://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Combinatorial-Mathematics-Applied-Introduction/dp/0201726343/ref=sr_1_1?crid=23QME5NSETJB5&keywords=discrete+and+combinatorial+mathematics&qid=1557679594&s=books&sprefix=discrete+and%2Cstripbooks%2C146&sr=1-1) but apparently a lot of students find it difficult